# How can I create 2D objects?

Tags: objects

Is there any setting to make a 2D object? Or at least an object that can only be seen from 2 angles.
I tried making an object very skinny, but it did not work.

Comment: If you don't like the answers so far we need a bit more information. What did you try to achieve and what did not work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also use curves and keep them as 2D:

[image]
[image]

Comment: see also: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Curves/Editing and http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Curves

Answer (score 2):

Just make it infinity skinny ;)

<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>*> Mesh > Plane* will add a 2D plane.

Such a 2D object cannot be seen edge on:

[image]